# Update RecyclerView onChildChanged Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update my recyclerview but i'm getting error of

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1

```
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploads.add(upload);
                adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, uploads);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

          //      uploads.clear();
                String key=dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploads.set(uploads.indexOf(key),upload);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Help me with this logic.
If i didn't do anything in `onChildChanged` except `Notify` then it will create duplicate `child`

Comment: Most likely `uploads.indexOf(key)` doesn't find the key so it returns `-1`. It's hard to speculate why this is based on the code you shared. What type is `uploads` for example? How does it find the index for a key?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i was expecting your response :) . well i've developed working solution for this. i need to modify this code or post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I Got it

**You will need two arrays to do this.**

```
// Lists
private final List<ChatModel> lIndividualChats = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mKeys = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Then**

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,
                        @Nullable String s) {

   ChatModel chatModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
   lIndividualChats.add(chatModel);
   chatsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
   mKeys.add(key);

}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,
                          @Nullable String s) {

   ChatModel chatModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
   String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

   int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);
   lIndividualChats.set(index,
                        chatModel);
   chatsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

By using another array of simple string type you will be able to access the index of the model array list.